# How to find the position of same rows from one 2D array to another 2D array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```
import numpy as np

# Create two sample dataframes
df1 = np.array([[0.000000,0.000000,0.000000],
[0.090000,0.000000,0.000000],
[0.190000,0.000000,0.000000],
[0.280000,0.000000,0.000000],
[0.380000,0.000000,0.000000],
[0.470000,0.000000,0.000000],
[0.570000,0.000000,0.000000],
[0.660000,0.000000,0.000000],
[0.760000,0.000000,0.000000],
[0.850000,0.000000,0.000000]])

df2 = np.array([[0.470000,0.000000,0.000000],
[0.570000,0.000000,0.000000],
[0.660000,0.000000,0.000000],
[0.760000,0.000000,0.000000],
[0.850000,0.000000,0.000000]
])

df3 = np.where(np.isclose(df1[:, np.newaxis], df2))[0]

print(df3)
```

I want to find the postion of df2 in df1 and the correct answer is
`[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`
but the python output is `[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9]`
which does not make sense. How can I change the code to find the postion of df2 in df1 correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to match the non-zeros, you can remove them:

```
np.where(np.isclose(np.where(df1!=0, df1, np.nan)[:, None], df2))[0]
```

Output:

```
array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

If you want a full match, including zeros (row per row), you can use:

```
out = np.where(np.isclose(df1[:, None], df2).all(2))[0]
```

Output: `array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])`

Answer (score 1):

One way to full match:

```
np.argwhere(np.isin(df1, df2).all(axis=1))

array([[0],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: `isin` flattens the array, so you could shuffle `df2` and get the same result. Not sure if this is the expected logic.

Comment: Hmm.. you are right mozway